# Building Speech Dataset for RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, speech-recognition, mfcc

I'm trying to do a RNN classification for Speech Data using Tensorflow or Keras. The classifier is for an isolated word speech.That is, a single word sound is to be fetched to the RNN for classification and it must classify the word sound. Till now what i have done is extracted the MFCC's of the sound and since each sound is of varying length the MFCC's generated are also of varying length. For eg For the word '1' the MFCC generated will have a shape of (28,26) and for the word '2' it will be (24,26). The length of speech sound is varying and how shall i model this data for RNN classification. In all the examples and tutorials the Input data is of same length but in my case input data is of varying length.  How to model this kind of problem. What shall be my X (input ) and Y(output) variables be?

Comment: One of the key advantages of RNNs it to enable sequential input, can't you just feed the MFCCs in to your classifier frame by frame? Each frame would need to have the same length, but this should be the case anyway.

Comment: Questions about designing machine learning models are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. You should consider researching on how fixed size features are extracted from audio data. Once you have a more specific question, it might be suitable for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)